# read particular csv file inside tar.gz file in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, tar

I have these three files file_1.csv, file_2.csv, file_3.json inside tar.gz file. I want to read file_1.csv in spark dataframe

something like this:

```
df = spark.read.csv("s3://my_bucket/key/my_file_.tar.gz/file_1.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a really good way of accessing a file in a tarball (`.tar.gz/.tar`) without extracting the files first.
Here's a [reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208482/view-a-file-in-a-tar-archive-without-extracting-it) to someone else's question about opening files in a tarball without extracting first.